# Calling .delayed() on workers

Tags: dask

Several places in the documentation (e.g., https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/phases-of-computation.html) imply that `.delayed()` is or should be used on the local machine. I'd actually like to have a worker both build up the graph and call `.compute()`. It seems to work when I test it, but I want to make sure I'm not asking for pain down the road -- e.g. could I deadlock the cluster if all the workers are waiting on a graph and unavailable to do real work?

Comment: Short answer - yes, this can cause serious problems. There are more advanced ways of scheduling tasks but in general, workers scheduling jobs can cause the scheduler to take on tasks in a sub-optimal manner, e.g. by processing the first task in each scheduled job's tree first, then moving to the second, until the cluster has run out of memory before any tasks have been completed. One remote worker submitting a job is fine, but I've yet to see a good case where a many-scheduling-many pattern works well.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Okay, thanks. I'm not worried about memory (just doing long compute tasks) but it sounds like it could still be rough. The docs say that futures can "launch tasks from tasks" (https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html and https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html#real-time) -- will they have the same problem? I would think they'd use the same or at least a very similar underlying mechanism.

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - you absolutely can do this, and each task, if it finishes, should return the correct result. The issue I'm describing only occurs if the success of your job depends on workers tackling one set of tasks, then clearing their memory and moving to the next set. This is a fairly common situation in map-reduce workflows I've seen, but if your application does not have this issue, than there's no reason why you can't have workers issue their own tasks.

Comment: Thanks again -- I went ahead and did a larger scale test and it does in fact work just fine, although I'm definitely seeing that behavior where it balances all the jobs evenly rather than doing the earlier jobs first. Not ideal, but not a huge issue either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dask.delayed either on a local machine or on a distributed cluster.  The API doesn't really care where it's run.